# Programatically set suffix of TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

How can one set the suffix of [TextInputLayout](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields/#outlined-text-field) programatically in code? I didn't find any function regarding this.

---

[image]

Comment: Is [the `setSuffixText()` method](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout.java#L2267) not resolving for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This required minimum version `1.2.0-alpha01`.

Comment: True, I am using 1.1.0 (stable).

Answer (score 0):

try version 1.2.0-alpha01 to support suffix.